# Does electronic cigarette juice require a hechsher?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, tobacco-cig-smoking

Does [electronic cigarette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_cigarette) "juice" need to be kosher (require a hechsher)?
Does it matter what flavor the juice is?

Answer (score 10):

According to the [CRC-Chicago](http://www.crcweb.org/faq/faqanswer.php?faqid=69) it needs a Hashgacha

> Does the juice or flavor for electronic cigarettes pose kashrus
>   issues?
>
> Yes. Electronic cigarettes convert a specially formulated liquid into
>   a vapor which the person inhales in a manner that mimics the way one
>   inhales from a traditional cigarette. The liquid (which is sometimes
>   called “juice”, “smoke-juice” or similar names) typically includes
>   kosher-sensitive ingredients such as glycerin and flavors, and since
>   the person imbibes the liquid/vapor, Rav Schwartz said that the liquid
>   must be certified as kosher. We contacted a number of manufacturers
>   who claim to use only kosher raw materials but there is no independent
>   agency who certifies that claim, and therefore we are unable to
>   recommend those products. [As with all medical issues, one should
>   consult with their doctor before deciding to use or not use electronic
>   cigarettes.]

Comment: Do they require cigarettes to have a hechsher?

Comment: @user6591: I do not know. However you can [ask that](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as a separate question.

Comment: Is there more of a reason to require a hechsher on the electronic kind?

Comment: @user6591: Perhaps there are more additives. It is less pure.

Comment: Glycerin (which produces the clouds of vapour) can be made from fats or oils which can have animal, vegetable or mineral origins, though it is usually made from vegetable sources. This is then mixed with nicotine and flavours, and in particular the flavours can have a variety of sources, though usually synthetic.

Comment: Glycerin is also found in regular cigarettes so they should seemingly also need a hechsher?

Comment: On its face this is starting to sound ridiculous. Do we need a hechsher for compressed air now? or shoes? Glycerin is only an issue when the item in question is eaten/drunk. THIS IS NOT A FOOD ITEM, so why do the ingredients matter? I guarantee no one is inspecting tobacco leaves for insects, even though that's "imbibed" in EXACTLY the same way. Inhalation is not halachic consumption.

Answer (score 1):

They are different opinions, CRC holds that you need a Hechsher but they certify [www.dropsmoke.com](http://www.dropsmoke.com) juices, they are other Rabbonim who hold that you don't need a Hechsher.

Comment: Source?.........

Comment: No source in writing, sorry. You can see the CRC certificate here http://dropsmoke.com/crc-certificate