# Is vaping prohibited?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, tobacco-cig-smoking

With the rising popularity of vaping and electronic cigarettes, many might consider turning to them to stop smoking or to at least divert their habit to a healthier alternative. However, the liquids are made using food products. Would the liquids need to be kosher certified even though they aren't being digested? Is the activity itself allowed?

Comment: Good question, IMHO... The smoking question is covered by http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10513/is-one-allowed-to-smoke, but vaping?  I think the "crux of the biscuit"(Thanks and RIP, Frank!) is that it's still a nicotine delivery system, and nicotine use is an addiction, and thereby harmful to the person's behavior, at the least, and their health, at the most.  Also, propylene glycol, alias antifreeze, is probably NOT the best substance to put into your system on a daily basis, but nobody(like the FDA)has shown it to be a killer yet, so it's still the vapor of choice in the market.

Comment: what about people who vape without nicotine?

Comment: Why would you think that the "activity itself" would *not* be allowed? ...if it's all kosher, then shouldn't it be fine, automatically?

Comment: @shokhet I don't know, which is why I am asking! :P

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52599/does-electronic-cigarette-juice-require-a-hechsher/52600#52600

Comment: @Gary There's some newer research that suggests that electronic cigarette usage causes immediate short term damage to the lungs and weakens the immune system. Also, when used at a high voltage level, the amount of formaldehyde inhaled is much higher than it is in regular cigarettes. There is also some [preliminary evidence](http://www.tobaccoinduceddiseases.com/content/12/S1/A34) that the delivery system of the e-cigarette itself, rather than the nicotine contained therein, it harmful to lung function.

Comment: @Fred - ....surprise, surprise, surprise...anything run through the lungs besides air on a daily basis seems to me to be a bad idea...

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**  According to YU Rosh Yeshiva R' [Daniel Stein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Stein_(rabbi)) (who cites the opinions of R' [Herschel Schachter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershel_Schachter) & R' [Mordechai Willig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Willig) among others), **vaping should be avoided entirely, as it entails  the inhalation of known toxins and possibly forbidden foods**.

---

**R' Daniel Stein** published a TorahWeb.org article titled "[Are Vaping and E-Cigarettes Kosher?](https://www.torahweb.org/torah/special/2018/rdst_vaping.html)" in 2018, in which he discusses two main issues with vaping:

### 1) Inhalation of dangerous toxins:

> In January of 2018 [The National Academies of Sciences, Engineering, and Medicine](http://www8.nationalacademies.org/onpinews/newsitem.aspx?RecordID=24952) published a comprehensive study which concluded that while the use of e-cigarettes appears less harmful than conventional cigarettes, e-cigarettes emit numerous known toxins aside from nicotine. Studies have shown that e-cigarette emissions can include potentially toxic levels of formaldehyde, arsenic, [benzene](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28273096), chromium, manganese, nickel, lead, zinc, and diacetyl, etc. Even though some of the ingredients in e-juice have been designated as safe when consumed at room temperature, when they are heated by a metal coil they produce toxic substances that are potentially dangerous. These findings have been discussed in many recent news columns including [Medical News Today](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/321006.php), [Newsweek](https://www.newsweek.com/vaping-news-lead-arsenic-and-other-toxins-inhaled-when-smoking-e-cigarettes-818733), and [The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/04/04/opinion/formaldehyde-diacetyl-e-cigs.html).

R' Stein goes on to cite more studies that seem to show that prolonged inhalation of these toxins can lead to an increased risk of cancer, heart disease, stroke, and respiratory distress.

#### Thus:

> Even though the precise long-term effects of regular e-cigarette use remains largely undefined, since it involves the frequent inhalation of known toxins, **Rav Hershel Schachter** shlit"a and **Rav Mordechai Willig** shlit"a believe that **there is already ample basis to assert that the use of e-cigarettes by non-smokers should provisionally be forbidden by virtue of the prohibition against self-endangerment** found in the pasuk "And you shall watch yourselves very well," pending the collection of definitive data.

### 2) Kashrus Issues:

> Often one of the core ingredients in the e-liquid is glycerin, a clear, odorless liquid with a thick consistency and sweet taste... Glycerin can be derived from vegetable oils or animal fats and they are used interchangeably. **Therefore, a food product containing glycerin typically requires kashrus supervision** despite the insistence of the manufacturer that it uses strictly vegetable glycerin. Arguably, a glycerin product that is turned into an aerosol or vapor and then inhaled should also require kashrus certification. Indeed, this is the opinion of the [Chicago Rabbinical Council](http://www.crcweb.org/faq/faqanswer.php?faqid=69) and reported to be the position of [Rav Shlomo Miller](http://www.frumtoronto.com/Blogger.asp?BlogCategoryID=98&ShowEntryID=15097) shlit"a as well.

R' Stein continues:

> Additionally, the **Magen Avraham** ([467:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.467.8?lang=bi&p2=Magen_Avraham.467.10&lang2=bi)) prohibits cigarettes containing beer-soaked tobacco on Pesach, even though the tobacco is presently inedible (see **Beis Meir**.) **[Rav Moshe Schick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Schick)** (Maharam Schick, Orach Chaim 242) explains that since the beer-soaked tobacco is designed for inhalation and it has a pleasant flavor when inhaled, the tobacco can still be considered fit for consumption and remains prohibited. This is presumably predicated upon the notion that inhalation can sometimes be considered a form of imbibing (see also [Magen Avraham 210:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.211?lang=bi&p2=Magen_Avraham.210.9&lang2=bi)). **Similarly, since the e-juice is intended for inhalation and enjoyable when inhaled, it would retain its status as a forbidden food and as a result it should require kashrus supervision**.

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer to [this question](http://www.dinonline.org/2013/03/15/electronic-cigarettes-on-pesach/) :

> The materials used in the cigarettes are not edible

I realize that the question was regarding its use on Pesach, and the answer states that they are not Chametz, b/c it is inedible. Therefore, something that is not considered food, has no concerns of Kashrut.

Comment: Where did you find "this question"? Who answered it? Please [edit] this answer so that it stands on its own without a click to the other resource.

Comment: Futhermore, how is it relevant to the question being asked which is not about cigarettes but specifically about a product made from edible materials....